# How add Post Format Theme Support to Wordpress Themes

Tags: wordpress, themes

Hi i has Wordpress Theme i added post format theme support code to my theme as below

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', 
array( 
    'aside', 
    'chat', 
    'gallery', 
    'image', 
    'link', 
    'quote', 
    'status', 
    'video', 
    'audio' 
) 
);
```

we know the wordpress support 10 post format types but i want add another post format type to my theme for example i want add `gallery2` and `video2` but when i add these formats don't appear within my admin theme please how i can add extra theme support to my theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after try for finding the new way for adding the new post formats out off the wordpress post formats i viewed that we can't add any other new post formats the wordpress only support this below formats

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', 
    array( 
        'aside', 
        'chat', 
        'gallery', 
        'image', 
        'link', 
        'quote', 
        'status', 
        'video', 
        'audio' 
    ) 
);
```